# How to store branching logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logic

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store/handle branching logic in my model.

A user would set up different rules and rule would be "If survey taker selects Answer 1, then show Questions 2, 3 and 4"

I have Question and Answer models, so I could store the rules and map them to the question and answer ID's as needed.

Just not sure from a database column standpoint how best to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

- Use a map:

  (Answer 1) -> (Q1, Q2, Q3)

As for *database schema*:
Given this table

> questionsTable: ID, CurrentAnswer, NextQuestion

```
select NextQuestion from questionsTable where CurrentQuestion='A1'
```

- You can also create a little brain with logical statements in conjunctive normal form (CNF):

> A1->Q1 ^ A1->Q2 ^ A1->Q3

or you could separate each implication as a separate statement.

Then evaluate these expressions. The result can then point to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Answers belongs to a single question (column answer_id).
Question: has_many :answers
Answer: belongs_to :question

For the follow up questions this may need some more work:
Questions can belong to (= follow) different answers and several Answers can have the same questions following them. So here you most likely need a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with an intermediate table that stores a question_id and an answer_id.